# useEffect keeps on eternal loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I was receiving this warning due to a missing denpendecy on useEffect:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      handleRadioGroup(value)
    }, [value])
```

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleRadioGroup'. Either include it or remove the dependency array         react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

So I tried to use a useCallback, to only run the useEffect when this handleRadioGroup function changes.

```js
  const handleRadioSelection = useCallback((value) => {
  handleRadioGroup(value)
}, [handleRadioGroup])

useEffect(() => {
   handleRadioSelection(value)
}, [value, handleRadioSelection])
```

The problem is that, useEffect runs on enternal loop. If I print the useCallback function, it shows the same result every time. There is a way to remove this warning, without entering the eternal loop?

Comment: does next code work for you
`
 useEffect(() => {
      handleRadioGroup(value)
    }, [value, handleRadioGroup])
`

Comment: No, happens the same

Comment: without "useCallback", just "useEffect" with [value, handleRadioGroup] in dependency

Comment: It happens the same thing, I tried that before the useCallback solution

Comment: you should not use "useCallback" only to resolve the warning.
Something wrong with compiler, dependency [value, handleRadioGroup] - are valid.

Comment: I guess that since I am  running  handleRadioGroup in the useEffect every time  handleRadioGroup changes, useEffect is probably running the function and detectinh it changes, by the useEffect itself. Just don´t know how to outline this

Comment: You'll have to show all the code so we can see how the state is a managed. Right now it looks like there's 2 layers of unnecessary misdirection and you could just write `<RadioComponent onSelect={handleRadioGroup} />`

Comment: I didn´nt know about thist property, will checkout. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These infinite calls tend to happen because the value of the variable in your dependency array, in your case `value` or `handleRadioSelection`, changes within the hook. If this is your case then you'd have to rethink your logic to make sure the values don't change inside of it.